# DOMDocument How get element a from node?

Tags: php, parsing, domdocument

```
$url = file_get_contents('test.html');

$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($url, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$trs = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('tr');
foreach ($trs as $tr) {

    foreach ($tr->childNodes as $td){
        echo ' ' .$td->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #FFFF80;">1</td>
        <td><a href="test1.php" title="test1">test1</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #FFFF80;">2</td>
        <td><a href="test2.php" title="test2">test2</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #FFFF80;">3</td>
        <td><a href="test3.php" title="test3">test3</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

in result i get:

```
1 test1 2 test2 3 test3
```

But how get link from `td a`?

And how get html from `td`?

P.S.: i try with `$td->find('a');` and `$td->getElementsByTagName('a');` but it not work...

Answer (score 2):

I improved your code a little bit and this version works fine for me:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($url, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$trs = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('tr');
foreach ($trs as $tr) {
    foreach ($tr->childNodes as $td){
        if ($td->hasChildNodes()) { //check if <td> has childnodes
            foreach($td->childNodes as $i) {
                if ($i->hasAttributes()){ //check if childnode has attributes
                    echo $i->getAttribute("href") . "\n"; // get href="" attribute
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
test1.php
test2.php
test3.php
```